# Redirect 301 all files from a folder to one file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Good day everyone,

On my Wordpress website, I had a plugin that transfered external links through virtual site.com/go/abc123xyz style links.

I have removed the plugin but obviously, when I checked G webmaster tools, there were many Not Found errors for all of those virtual links.

All I wish to do is redirect all of those /go/links to one particular external link. I'm looking for a redirection rule which will redirect all links from the virtual /go/ folder to my specified link.

Would be really thankful if anyone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I just found the code added by that plugin in the .htaccess, it is still there ..

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^go/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?gocode=$1 [L,R]

How can I tweak this code in order to transfer all of those links from go/ folder to this link: mysitedotcom/out/link.php?id=0001 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
RewriteRule ^go/(.*) www.mysitedotcom/out/link.php?id=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

To your default htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So it should look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^go/(.*) /out/link.php?id=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I hope that answers your question and helps you.

Comment: Hi Giancarlo, thank you so much for the help! The exact code didn't work buy played around with it a little and this worked :)

`RewriteRule ^go/(.*) /out/link.php?id=0001 [R=301,NC,L]`

Thank you so much for the help!